# Facebook login/logout website

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook login logout in my website using facebook's PHP JS sdk. My problem is I cannot implement an independent login/logout option from actual facebook site. When I click the login button, it actually logs in the user's facebook and also my site. But, on clicking my site's logout button, It just logout from my site because I could only destroy my session. If I use `autologoutlink="true"` then it show the facebook logout button when logged in, but it does the logout of the actual facebook. I want to implement something like www.9gag.com.

I would really appreciate some help.

Here is my code, I am using CodeIgniter, and putting everything in the view/header.php .

```
?php

require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'app_id',
  'secret' => 'secret_key',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
//echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
$user = null;
  }
}

?>



<fb:login-button scope="email" autologoutlink="true" ></fb:login-button>
```

JS

```
    <script>



  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
      channelUrl : 'site_url', 
      cookie: true,
      logging: true,
      status: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });



FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {



 FB.api('/me', function(userInfo) {
    //console.log(userInfo);

          var options_ = {
                    'responsedata' : userInfo,
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'user/facebooklogin',
                    data: options_,
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(msg){
                        console.log(msg);
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });




    }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});

  });




    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });

  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());

</script>
```